# ForLoop for Multiple API data Pushes - With Code PHP

Tags: php, api, for-loop, curl

I am trying to send data to a server multiple times (for several different transactions) but the for loop won't work. 
One request going through fine, no problems, and I get a response but it will not loop though the whole array. Am I missing something simple?

Thanks.
PHP:

$array2 = array();

```
for ($i = 0; $i<=$numt; $i+=1) {
$arr = array('size' => $btcper, 'price' => $array[$i], 'side' => 'sell',
 'product_id' => 'BTC-USD');
array_push($array2, $arr);
};

for ($z = 0; $z<=$numt; $z+=1){
$output = json_encode($array2[$z]);


$key = $tkey;
$secret = $skey;
$passphrase = $passphrase1;

$time = time();
$url = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/orders";

$data = $time."POST"."/orders";
echo $data . "<br/>";

$hashinput = "$data"."$output";

$sign = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $hashinput, base64_decode($secret), true));                
echo $sign . "<br/>";

$headers = array(                
    'CB-ACCESS-KEY: '.$key,
    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN: '.$sign,
    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: '.$time,
    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE: '.$passphrase,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);



echo $url;

static $ch = null;
if (is_null($ch)) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'local server');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $output);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $res = curl_exec($ch)."\n"."\n";
    echo $res;

$myFile = "idfilesell".date('Y-m-d').".txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $res);
fclose($fh);


}exit;
};
?>
```

API Response:

```
https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/orders{"id":"41c4414c-8ec0-48f6-ad36-    25f0689c71a8","price":"300.00000000","size":"0.01000000","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}
```

Comment: Where is the array you're looping through? Also I don't see any loop logic in your curl calls.

Comment: I added the array for reference.

Comment: What do you mean by loop logic?

Answer (score 0):

I think that coinbase has quite sophisticated DOS protection. Maybe you hitting it by making requests too fast. Try to put some wait (one sec for example) inside you loop and see what happens.

Comment: I thought about that. Even with only 2 requests it rejects the 2nd so I think DOS may not be the issue.

Comment: Why do you have exit; inside your loop ? I suggest you remove it. This will stop your script instantly so no more iteration will take place ...